# mod_rewrite regular expression

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I have no experience with regular expression and tried few tricks with tools etc but did not get a robust solution.

Here is what I am trying to achieve. In coming requests can be in the following format:

```
http://whatever.com/search/s-<value>/i-<i value>/e-<e value>?query=<query value>&query1=<query1 value>

http://whatever.com/list/s-<value>/i-<i value>/e-<e value>?query=<query value>&query1=<query1 value>
```

With mod_rewrite I want to convert this to -

```
http://whatever.com/index.php?type=search&iid=<i value>&edd=<e-value>&query=<query value>&query1=<query1 value>

http://whatever.com/index.php?type=list&iid=<i value>&edd=<e-value>&query=<query value>&query1=<query1 value>
```

Note: the position of i-, e- etc may or may not appear at the same location. And, not all requests may have it.

Comment: where is the "s-value" after conversion?

Comment: Habeeb, s-value becomes stid=<value>. HTH.

Comment: The stid is not in question after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$   index.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)$   index.php?type=$1&$2id=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)$   index.php?type=$1&$2id=$3&$4id=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)/(.)-([^/]*)$   index.php?type=$1&$2id=$3&$4id=$5&$6id=$7 [L,QSA]
```

Here

```
 i-value is in $_GET['iid']
 s-value is in $_GET['sid']
 e-value is in $_GET['eid']
```

and

```
$_GET['query']
$_GET['query1']
```

also available.

Comment: Thanks Habeeb. This worked. But, just as another answer this works if all values are in correct position. However, the Url may or may not have s-, i- ... values. Is it possible to match based on s/e/i-(*) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by putting in your htaccess file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewirteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?query=<query value>&query1=<query1 value> index.php?type=search$iid=$2&edd=$3&query={QUERY_STRING}
```

You can use below as per your url parameter (i have assume that it may char and number both) :

```
1) [a-zA-Z0-9] for char + numbers
2) [a-zA-Z] for char
3) [0-9] for numbers
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I tried this solution and it works if all values are in correct position. However, the Url may or may not have s-, i- ... values. Is it possible to match based on s/e/i-(*) ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in **.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Just go to your index.php file then print $_GET variable, Do your stuffs there.

You will get path name in $_GET['q']. Then you can routing the request appropriate file or function.

Answer (score -1):

Read the PHP documentation on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).

PHP Documentation on PCRE is about the best on the net.  Don't bother using tools.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Jim. Would this not also mean that URL rewriting moves to PHP application from Apached httpd?

Comment: No. I should have been clearer.  I was just pointing out that if Apache's RewriteRules are generally compatible with PCRE rules and PHPnet has excellent documentation on the PCRE rules.  But it was really bad advice since all I did was create confusion.  Sorry

Comment: No sweat, Jim. Thanks for contributing.